# Degree of a field extension with a rational solution

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields

Let $S$ be a system of polynomial equations over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Assume that $S$ has a solution in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$.

Denote by $k$ the minimal number such that $S$ has $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$-rational solution.

How large can be $k$ (depends on $q$, the number of equations of $S$ and its degrees)?

Comment: Is it clear that there should be a dependence on $q$?  I guess it's obvious that $k$ is at most the product of the degrees of the elements of $S$, and it seems that, absent any other information (e.g., distribution of degrees), this has a chance of being best possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ of degree $d$. Then the smallest $k$ such that $f(x)$ has a root in $\mathbb F_{q^k}$ is $k=d$. More generally, let $f_i(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ of degree $d_i$. Then for $S=\{f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_r(x_r)\}$, the smallest $k$ such that $S$ has a solution $(x_1,\ldots,x_r)\in\mathbb F_{q^k}^r$ is $k=\text{LCM}(d_1,\ldots,d_r)$. So taking the $d_i$ to be pairwise relatively prime gives $k=d_1\cdots d_r$.

Are you assuming at least that there exists a solution over $\overline{\mathbb F}_q$?

Comment: Yes, I have such assumption, thank you.